# Exception in Google AdWords api v201710

Tags: java, google-ads-api

I am getting this exception when I am trying to make my first api call

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: No group found for service: v201710.CampaignService
>       at com.google.api.ads.adwords.lib.conf.AdWordsApiConfiguration.getServiceUrlGroup(AdWordsApiConfiguration.java:64)
>       at com.google.api.ads.adwords.lib.client.AdWordsServiceDescriptor.getEndpointAddress(AdWordsServiceDescriptor.java:83)
>       at com.google.api.ads.common.lib.factory.helper.BaseAdsServiceClientFactoryHelper.createAdsServiceClient(BaseAdsServiceClientFactoryHelper.java:73)
>       at com.google.api.ads.common.lib.factory.AdsServiceClientFactory.getServiceClient(AdsServiceClientFactory.java:76)
>       at com.google.api.ads.common.lib.factory.BaseAdsServiceClientFactory.getServiceClientAsInterface(BaseAdsServiceClientFactory.java:81)
>       at com.google.api.ads.common.lib.factory.BaseServices.get(BaseServices.java:45)
>       at google.adwords.axis.v201710.basicoperations.GetCampaigns.runExample(GetCampaigns.java:63)
>       at google.adwords.axis.v201710.basicoperations.GetCampaigns.main(GetCampaigns.java:56)

whereas version 201702 works fine,

is anyone having the same issues?